# Error: Could not find or load main class MyCSVParser

Tags: java, terminal, compilation

I have a .class that I've compiled from a .java

```
package csvExam.MyCSVParser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MyCSVParser {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        String csvFile = "/Users/dbaug/Desktop/idestuff/csvExam/testme.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        if(csvFile==null){

            System.out.println("no CSV File found, try again.");

        }else{

            try {

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] mainLine = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                    System.out.println("am I reading anything");

                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to compile using javac MyCSVParser.java and I received a MyCSVParser.class
both of these files sit in "C:\Users\dbaug\Desktop\idestuff\csvExam"

my %PATH% is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer
>   Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program
>   Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\dbaug\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\dbaug\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;

where you can see ";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;" at the bottom.

in Environmental Variables I have variable path set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin"

Below are all the inputs and results I encounter.

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.316] (c) 2018 Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\dbaug>cd c:\
>
> c:>java -classpath C:\Users\dbaug\Desktop\idestuff\csvExam
>   MyCSVParser Error: Could not find or load main class MyCSVParser
>
> c:>java -cp C:\Users\dbaug\Desktop\idestuff\csvExam MyCSVParser
>   Error: Could not find or load main class MyCSVParser
>
> c:>cd C:\Users\dbaug\Desktop\idestuff\csvExam
>
> C:\Users\dbaug\Desktop\idestuff\csvExam>java MyCSVParser Error: Could
>   not find or load main class MyCSVParser
>
> C:\Users\dbaug\Desktop\idestuff\csvExam>cd
>   C:\Users\dbaug\Desktop\idestuff
>
> C:\Users\dbaug\Desktop\idestuff>java csvExam.MyCSVParser Error: Could
>   not find or load main class csvExam.MyCSVParser
>
> C:\Users\dbaug\Desktop\idestuff>

I'm not trying to do anything special besides just trying to get a .class to run through terminal, as that's my next step from an IDE to validate my programs working. However I've been stumped all day over what I might be doing wrong and I'm just not sure. I run Windows 10, trying to use Java JDK jdk1.8.0_191, I downloaded from oracle java website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I don't know what I was doing wrong, but I changed package csvExam;
I now cd to the directory and can "java csvExam.MyCSVParser"